# $and operator returns incorrect result in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find one product who's id matches given id and also want to know if it's quantity will still be greater or equal to the sold quantity (after adding the sold quantity which will be sold later in the process).

```
const product = await Product.findOne(
    {
        $expr: {
            $and: [
                { _id: id },
                { $gte: ["$quantity", { $sum: ["$soldQuantity", quantity] }] }
            ]
        }
    }
);
```

(here **quantity** is a constant who's value is **2** and **id** is an **ObjectId**)
what I've achieved so far is if I turn **$gte into $lte** I get the **right result** but **$gte returns me false result**, which **should return an empty object** instead if conditions did not meet.
I'm using mongoDB **version 4.2**

Schema has:

```
Schema({
     quantity: {
         type: Number,
         required: true
     },
     soldQuantity: {
         type: Number,
         default: 0
    }
})
```

Comment: Post the document you are using to test  your query.